# Insert Text Field Into PHP Table

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together a PHP table shown below that that outputs a list of uploaded files.

```
echo("<table style='border-collapse: collapse' class='Grid' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
    foreach($files as $mvcfile)
    {
        echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td>");echo("<img src='phpuploader/resources/circle.png' border='0' />");echo("</td>");
        echo("<td>");echo($mvcfile->FileName);echo("</td>");
        //echo("<td>");echo($mvcfile->FileSize);echo("</td>");
        echo("</tr>");
```

I'm now trying to add another line to the table incorporating a text field which holds one of my PHP variable as shown below:

`echo("<td>");echo(input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?php echo $mvcfile->FileName; ?>");echo("</td>");`

I've had a look at several posts on this and other sites and I thought I'd understood what I needed to do, but clearly not as I'm receiving this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/formmanualstarttest.php on line 97`

with line 97 being the line I'm trying to introduce.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: an importan thing you have to understand: there are no tables in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="' . htmlentities($mvcfile->FileName) . '" />';
echo "</td>";
```

1. Input was not an HTML tag,
2. That string was not quoted, hence the error message: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`
3. Your code was already inside `<?php ?>` tags, so in your `echo input` the additional `<?php echo $mvc ...` was unnecessary.
4. I wrapped the filename in [`htmlentites`](http://php.net/htmlentities) for safe HTML output. `"` probably isn't common in a filename, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td>".'<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="'.$mvcfile->FileName.'" /></td>';
```

Explanation: echo needs no (). I removed that. Strings need either ' or ", added that [that caused the error message]. And . is the sing for concatenation.